# setValue of FormControl to array of an object in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have an array of an object that has data from my API that I want to bind to my form control.
This is my array of an object from my API and the same in console log.

```js
[
  {
    "dalelNo": "11010101",
    "dalelDesc": "صندوق المركز الرئيسي",
    "dalelDescE": "",
    "dalelType": 0,
    "dalelNature": 0,
    "dalelMax": 0,
    "dalelCurrency": "S.R",
    "dalelActive": 0,
    "dalelCenter": 0,
    "dalelNotice": "",
    "dalelUserNo": 5,
    "brnchNo": 4,
    "brnchDesc": "مستودع فرع 335",
    "brnchDebit": "1101",
    "brnchCredit": "11010101",
    "brnchNotice": null,
    "brnchUserNo": null
  }
]
```

I've tried this code

```js
  loadBranchesData() {
    this._branches.getBranchePost(this.routeParameterID).subscribe(data => {
      this.existingbranches = data;
      console.log(this.existingbranches);
      console.log(data);
      this.form.controls["brnchDesc"].setValue([{data:data.brnchDesc}]);
    });
```

but it binds in my form control input `[object Object]`

Comment: how do you want to look formControl?

Comment: it's an edit page it consists of a bunch of inputs and I want to bind in this inputs my data coming from my API .. i tried to receive these data in array but nothing is binded

Comment: Is your form control an input field?If you are binding an array to input field you will get this input field

Comment: Yes, but I've set value for a specific controller, but [0] was the missing part as I understand that I should target the array of objects I need @SayoojVR

Comment: Ok. Make the question conveys what exactly you want. So everyone can understand and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that's I should put [0] after my variable or "data", to be like that, as I understand that I should target the array of objects I need

```js
  loadBranchesData() {
    this._branches.getBranchePost(this.routeParameterID).subscribe(data => {
      this.branches = data;
      this.form.patchValue({
        brnchDesc: this.branches[0].brnchDesc,
        brnchDebit: this.branches[0].brnchDebit,
        dalelDesc: this.branches[0].dalelDesc,
        brnchCredit: this.branches[0].brnchCredit,
        brnchNotice: this.branches[0].brnchNotice,
      })
    });
  }
```

Thanks all.